# Is $\binom{N}{b}\equiv a\mod N,$ $a\neq 0$, only possibly when $\gcd(N,b)>1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

Let $0\leq b<N$. If $N$ is prime, then $\binom{N}{b}\equiv 0\mod N$ for all such $b$. For $N$ composite, can it be shown that $\binom{N}{b}\equiv a\mod N,$ $a\neq 0$, is only possible for $\gcd(b,N)>1$?

Comment: I'd love to see your own work on this question, and hear more details about what has you stuck.   As is, this question completely lacks context, and reads like an assigned exercise for you to complete. "Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc."

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this follows from [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) on binomial coefficients.